# Python asyncio two tasks and only one is running

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am new to python and struggling to understand why my coroutine is not working.

In the current code, the only one job is running and another is always stays idle. Why?

```
class Worker:    
    def job1_sync(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            print('JOB A:', count)
            count = count + 1

    def job2_sync(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            print('JOB B:', count)
            count = count + 1

    async def job1(self):
        await self.job1_sync()

    async def job2(self):
        await self.job2_sync()

    worker = Worker()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(worker.job1(), worker.job2()))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asyncio does not do multi-tasking or multithreading. What it does is it schedules tasks within one thread, using a cooperative model.

That is, the event loop runs again when the current task `await`s something that will "block", and only then it schedules another task. Under the hood, async functions are coroutines, and calls to `await` make the corouting yield to the event loop, which resumes it a later point, when awaited condition arises.

Here you never await anything, so job1 never relinquishes control, so the event loop never has a chance to distribute computing power to other tasks.

Now if your job was to actually relinquish control, say by triggering a delay, then your code would work:

```
async def job1_sync(self):      # note the async : only async functions can await
    count = 0
    while True:
        print('JOB A:', count)
        count = count + 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # main even loop gets control
```

TLDR: asyncio is useful for what it says: doing stuff asynchronously, allowing other tasks to make progress while current task waits for something. Nothing runs in parallel.

Comment: Make sense. I misunderstood entire concept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The OP might be looking for is `await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.job1_sync)`. `async def job1_sync` contradicts its own naming - presumably the whole point of `job1_sync` is that it invokes legacy or third-party sync code that might not be easy to change to async.

Comment: Well, perhaps. Although I think someone already knowing asyncio and going after the problem you describe would have asked the question in a different way, like, how to use threading/ipc and asyncio together. So my guess was the code was a full example from someone learning to use asyncio.